Sending json to an API as a string causes an error, but sending the dotnet object does not
Language: C# .net framework 4.8 Visual Studio 2019.
I was trying to send a json to an API, and if I send it as a string:
string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataToSend, Formatting.Indented);


var result = await urlApi.
          WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).
          PostJsonAsync(jsonString).
          ReceiveString();

NOTE: dataToSend is a dotnet object. I am using newtonsoft's json framework: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json, to serialize the object to a json. I am using flurl: https://flurl.dev/, to send the json.
The remote host answer with an error:
{
    "Status": "-1",
    "Description": "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
    "Result": null
}

However, when I send the object directly:
var result = await urlApi.
         WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).
         PostJsonAsync(dataToSend).
         ReceiveString();

NOTE: dataToSend is a dotnet object.
I don't get any error.
I want to know why sending the json as a string causes an error.
¿Do you know why?
¿How can I find out?

I strongly suspect that if you look at the HTTP request on the wire, you'll see that the JSON represents exactly what you've said it should: a string. I suspect it'll be something like: "{ \"x\": \"Some value\", \"y\": \"Some other value\" }" (including all the quotes and backslashes). That's the JSON representation of a string.

Agreed, it looks like you are double-serializing your JSON.  The question JSON.NET Parser seems to be double serializing my objects deals with this on the server side; you're basically doing the same thing on the client side.

Your problem is that you are double-serializing your JSON.  The extension method you are using, GeneratedExtensions.PostJsonAsync(this string url, object body, ...), works as follows:

Creates a FlurlRequest and sends an asynchronous POST request.
url - This URL.
body - An object representing the request body, which will be serialized to JSON.

Since your jsonString is already serialized to JSON, it gets serialized a second time as a JSON string literal, causing the remote host to return the error you see.
If for some reason you need to serialize the JSON manually, you can post it using Flurl.Http.Content.CapturedJsonContent:
var result = await urlApi.
    WithTimeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeout)).
    PostAsync(new CapturedJsonContent(jsonString)).
    ReceiveString();

